# HTML - Button on click display value of textfield

Tags: html, button, textfield

I use a textfield with code:

```
<input type = "text" size = "2" maxlength = "2" name = "myname">
```

and a button with:

```
<button type = "button" onclick = "alert('Clicked!')">Print</button>
```

Now, as I click on it, a message/alert pops saying `Clicked!`. How can I make it just display whatever value was on the textfield instead? Ty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
<input type="text" id="test" size="2" maxlength="2" name="myname">
<button type="button" onclick="alert(document.getElementById('test').value);">Print</button>
```

A working example you can find here: http://jsfiddle.net/sebastianbrosch/x8zzvd5s/

**Explanation**
You have to add a id to your textfield (here `test`). On the `alert()` you can get the value of the textfield with `document.getElementById('test').value`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! Works fine and I accepted it. One last question I got though is, if I have to declare an id as shown, then what does the name stand for? Again, thanks for the help (I am new to html)

Comment: the name is used for the `POST`. If you are using PHP to get this fields sent by a form you can get the value with `$_POST['myname']`.

Answer (score 1):

if you are doing this to print a person's name or something using PHP then it should be like this:
 add this in your body of html:

```
<form name="form1" action="registration.php" method="POST"   onsubmit="myFunction()" >
 <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
 <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

you can validate this field using javascript on submit as:(write this in head tag of html)

```
 <script>
  var name=document.getElementById("name").value;
  myFunction()
    {
     if(name!="")
      {
     return true;
       }
        else
         {
   //show alert.
     return false;
        }
        }
          </script>
```

In PHP you can print the name user entered in the text by(reg.php):

```
<?php
   $name=$_POST['name'];//it is the name of the control field
   echo $name;
 ?>
```